# Couldn't find User without an ID rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and i keep getting this error

### Couldn't find User without an ID

from:

```
    class UserController < ApplicationController
     def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
     end
    end
```

this is what i have;

#### model/user.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :email, presence: true

      has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy

      has_many :purchasing, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: "buyer_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :sell, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: "seller_id", dependent: :destroy
 

      has_many :purchased, class_name: "Archive", foreign_key: "buyer_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :sales, class_name: "Archive", foreign_key: "seller_id", dependent: :destroy

      has_many :selling_rooms, class_name: "Room", foreign_key: "seller_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :buying_room, class_name: "Room", foreign_key: "buyer_id", dependent: :destroy

     def can_buy?(listing_price)
      if self.points >= listing_price
        true
      else
        false
      end
     end

     def withdraw(listing_price)
      self.points -= listing_price
     end


    def purchasing_list
     purchasing.includes(:seller, :listing)
    end

    def purchased_list
     purchased.includes(:seller, :listing)
    end

    def sell_list
     sell.includes(:seller, :listing)
    end

    def sales_list
     sales.includes(:seller, :listing)
    end
  end
```

#### resources

```
    resources :users
```

I looked around but all i could find was something saying that it is looking for a resource that doesn't exist.

Comment: When do you get this error? What URL are you getting? Are you sure the user with that ID exists?

Comment: You have no id. We have no idea why not because you didn't provide any information about what leads to the code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that  `params[:id]` not present.

first try to check with putting in

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
 def show
   logger"-----#{params[:id]}---"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

if its empty then pass `id` from the `link` from where you getting this error

```
ex. localhost:3000/users/1
```

here `params[:id] == 1` must be

Answer (score 2):

Some where in your form which redirects you to the users show page you should send the id or send the object itself.

`<%= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %>`

or

`<%= link_to 'Show', user_path(user.id) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **params**, As I know you are getting `params[:id] = nil`.

Try to pass **:id** in your params or you can check it by hard-coding it.

Comment: How do you pass the id in your params?

Comment: In your view where you put show link, just add parameter to that show path with with user_id. Like show_path(id: user.id) and it come in your params in show method

Answer (score 0):

Check yo console!

In the parameters that are sent through in the request that is blowing up, have a look at exactly what the id your sending through is. Is it a `user_id`? is it an `id`? Your controller is expecting an `id` so make sure you are passing it one.

If you're passing an entire object you will need to specify. Eg. If you're passing through a `user` you'll need to pass through a `user.id` instead because your controller is expecting an ID which is typically a number. `user` will give the whole object, `user.id` will give just the number value, which is the ID in this case. Then with that number the controller action can find the relevant user in the database.